# Deploying Gradle Project to Gitlab Runner for CI/CD integration

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am teaching myself how to setup a CI pipeline for a Gradle Project. In order to get started I used the base Gradle template for the gitlab runner but I am not sure where to go from here in terms of successfully building and deploying.It looks like the runner cannot detected my .gradle but when I change my GRADLE_USER_HOME to point to the correct folder it continues to fail. Are there steps I am missing. I am not looking to add deploy step just yet. Just creating a successful build.

```
    image: gradle:alpine``

    # Disable the Gradle daemon for Continuous Integration servers as correctness
    # is usually a priority over speed in CI environments. Using a fresh
    # runtime for each build is more reliable since the runtime is completely
    # isolated from any previous builds.
    variables:
    GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

    before_script:
        - GRADLE_USER_HOME="$(pwd)/TestGradle/.gradle"
        - export GRADLE_USER_HOME

    build:
        stage: build
        script: gradle --build-cache assemble
        cache:
            key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
            policy: push
            paths:
                - build
                - .gradle

    test:
        stage: test
        script: gradle check
        cache:
            key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
            policy: pull
            paths:
               - build
               - .gradle
```

This is the output I receive from the build job:

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 14.8.0~beta.44.g57df0d52 (57df0d52)[0;m
[0K  on blue-3.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default zxwgkjAP[0;m
section_start:1646774895:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "docker+machine" executor[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing Docker executor with image gradle:alpine ...[0;m
[0KPulling docker image gradle:alpine ...[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:2fd2f971c78001483ef56512bd107d6417966255fbc7f21d57b9467b708496c8 for gradle:alpine with digest gradle@sha256:fb36dfe0cbfd220481ef0ecbcec5bda9feb51565633d76a03eb2d5dc38836b78 ...[0;m
section_end:1646774916:prepare_executor
[0Ksection_start:1646774916:prepare_script
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing environment[0;m[0;m
Running on runner-zxwgkjap-project-34169945-concurrent-0 via runner-zxwgkjap-shared-1646774857-c4b5a749...
section_end:1646774919:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1646774919:get_sources
[0K[0K[36;1mGetting source from Git repository[0;m[0;m
[32;1m$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"[0;m
[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 20...[0;m
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/eaowusu18/NSBEbackend/.git/
[32;1mCreated fresh repository.[0;m
[32;1mChecking out 650ce284 as main...[0;m

[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
section_end:1646774920:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1646774920:restore_cache
[0K[0K[36;1mRestoring cache[0;m[0;m
[32;1mNot downloading cache main due to policy[0;m
section_end:1646774921:restore_cache
[0Ksection_start:1646774921:step_script
[0K[0K[36;1mExecuting "step_script" stage of the job script[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:2fd2f971c78001483ef56512bd107d6417966255fbc7f21d57b9467b708496c8 for gradle:alpine with digest gradle@sha256:fb36dfe0cbfd220481ef0ecbcec5bda9feb51565633d76a03eb2d5dc38836b78 ...[0;m
[32;1m$ GRADLE_USER_HOME="$(pwd)/TestGradle/.gradle"[0;m
[32;1m$ export GRADLE_USER_HOME[0;m
[32;1m$ gradle --build-cache assemble[0;m

Welcome to Gradle 7.4!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Aggregated test and JaCoCo reports
 - Marking additional test source directories as tests in IntelliJ
 - Support for Adoptium JDKs in Java toolchains

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/release-notes.html

To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Directory '/builds/eaowusu18/NSBEbackend' does not contain a Gradle build.

A Gradle build should contain a 'settings.gradle' or 'settings.gradle.kts' file in its root directory. It may also contain a 'build.gradle' or 'build.gradle.kts' file.

To create a new Gradle build in this directory run 'gradle init'

For more detail on the 'init' task see https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_init_plugin.html

For more detail on creating a Gradle build see https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

* Try:
> Run gradle init to create a new Gradle build in this directory.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
section_end:1646774926:step_script
[0Ksection_start:1646774926:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[0K[36;1mCleaning up project directory and file based variables[0;m[0;m
section_end:1646774927:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
[0;m
```